# rpmbuild -rp option is not supported?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I've got a shell script with some rpmbuild workflow from a previous project and there is one command which is failing with an error unsupported option.

The command is this:

```
rpmbuild --nodeps --define '_builddir /tmp/build' --define '_sourcedir /tmp/source' -rp package_source.src.rpm
```

As per the documentation this *-rp* option is supported but I'm unable to run the rpmbuild command with this option.
Here's the man-pages link: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rpmbuild.8.html#SYNOPSIS

The error message I'm getting is this:

```
rpmbuild: arguments to --root (-r) must begin with a /
```

Update1: my rpm version is *4.11.3* on CentOS7 and the man-page mentioned above is the latest version.

With the current version I've `rpmbuild --help` output is not listing this *-rp* or any other -r options.

So how do I get the same result using the rpm version which doesn't have this option?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The -rp option has to be on the first position.